# TouchID does not lock MacBook Pro anymore on macOS Big Sur 11.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, big-sur, touch-id

Is it just me or this feature was removed after updating to Big Sur 11.2?

Comment: Does TouchID _unlock_ your MBP? Have you tried disabling TouchID, thus removing the fingerprint information, and then reentered the fingerprints from scratch?

Comment: Instead of just rolling back edits from others please also consider the clarification questions asked in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is apparently a somewhat common issue after upgrading to Big Sur or even the 11.1 -> 11.2 upgrade.

You need to do a [SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and possibly a [PRAM](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-3604) reset.

I was able to clear it by powering off the MacBook Pro, holding down the power button on the touch bar for >10 seconds, and then power back on.

Hope that works for you.